# How do I group by a column in a nested association in sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, group-by, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement the following SQL query using sequelize.js:

```
select
    practtype.description,
    SUM("chargevalue") as "categoryvalue"
from
    "public"."profees" as "profees"
inner join "public"."practitioners" AS "practitioner" on
    "profees"."practitionerid" = "practitioner"."practitionerid"
inner join public.practtypes as "practtype" on 
    "practitioner"."practtypeid" = "practtype"."practtypeid"
group by
    practtype.description
order by
    practtype.description;
```

I have the following associations set up in my `init-models.js` component:

```
profees.belongsTo(practitioners, { as: "practitioner", foreignKey: "practitionerid"});
practitioners.hasMany(profees, { as: "profees", foreignKey: "practitionerid"});
practitioners.belongsTo(practtypes, { as: "practtype", foreignKey: "practtypeid"});
practtypes.hasMany(practitioners, { as: "practitioners", foreignKey: "practtypeid"});
```

I'm struggling to find decent documentation or examples of how to specify the `group` clause of my sequelize query. Here's what I currently have:

```
    const feesSummary = await profees.findAll({
      attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn("SUM", sequelize.col("chargevalue")), "categoryvalue"],
        // ["chargevalue", "categoryvalue"],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: practitioners,
          as: "practitioner",
          required: true,
          attributes: ["surname"],
          include: [
            {
              model: practtypes,
              as: "practtype",
              required: true,
              attributes: ["description"],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      group: [
        [
          { model: practitioners, as: "practitioner" },
          { model: practtypes, as: "practtype" },
          "description",
        ],
      ],
      order: [
        [
          { model: practitioners, as: "practitioner" },
          { model: practtypes, as: "practtype" },
          "description",
          "ASC",
        ],
      ],
      // where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn("date_part", ["year", sequelize.col("chargedate")]), year)
    });
```

(I've commented out the where clause for the time being, as it's also giving me separate issues).

When I try to execute the sequelize query above, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown structure passed to order / group: { model: practitioners, as: 'practitioner' }
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.quote (/home/developer/medexpenses/medexps-service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:888:11)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.aliasGrouping (/home/developer/medexpenses/medexps-service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1418:17)
    at /home/developer/medexpenses/medexps-service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1343:82
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.selectQuery (/home/developer/medexpenses/medexps-service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1343:68)
    at PostgresQueryInterface.select (/home/developer/medexpenses/medexps-service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:954:27)
    at Function.findAll (/home/developer/medexpenses/medexps-service/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1753:47)
```

I'm using version 6.6.2 of sequelize.

Can anyone post an example of the correct way to formulate the `group` clause in the query above? The [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#grouping) suggests that

> The syntax for grouping and ordering are equal, except that grouping does not accept a direction as last argument of the array (there is no ASC, DESC, NULLS FIRST, etc).

which is why I formulated the `group` clause as I did, but I'm getting the error above nonetheless.